# How do I remove GIF emojis from Gboard?

Tags: keyboard, gboard

I can see how to remove emojis from Gboard, but is it possible to remove just the GIF emojis?

Answer (score -1):

Play Store -> GBoard -> Uninstall -> Select the three dots on upper right -> disable auto-update

This will mean that your version of GBoard is without gif functionality, as it was introduced in a later update[image]

Comment: Hi @Chris, thanks for the answer attempt, and the effort of putting a picture too...  However this doesn't really solve problem because it assumes someone has the old version, but the asker has the GIFs already... Keep trying and contributing!

Comment: This will only work if Gboard is installed as a system/built-in keyboard (it will say "Uninstall updates" instead to revert to the oldest version on the device). If it's installed as an additional/3rd-party keyboard, uninstalling and reinstalling it will still install the latest version with the GIF emoji feature already there.